# I am designing layout. how to print text like today yesterday and another day

Tags: android, kotlin

I am designing this layout can any one suggest me that how would i print this text like today yesterday and another day as per snapshot which i shared

Here Is my code:

```kotlin
object DateTimeUtils {

    private val calendar by lazy {
        Calendar.getInstance()
    }

    fun calculateTodayYesterday(time:Long):String {
        var label = ""

        label = when (time) {
            calendar.timeInMillis -> {
                "Today"
            }

            (time - 86400000) -> {
                "Yesterday"
            }

            else -> {
                val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
                sdf.format(time)
            }
        }
        return label
    }
}
```

Please suggest me any modification or provide me another code.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO looks like you forgot to add the layout image .. right now its not clear what exactly you want to do [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73301967/edit) your question with proper detail and title .

Comment: I am not able to edit post and not able to attach image and image link so i am pasting my image link here.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvSLfQcBDHBQjWxmj_m3cw_xHLs4?e=yZ3ivz

Comment: I think you are very likely to not get the results `"today"` and `"yesterday"`, because each of them would only be printed if `time` exactly matched a millisecond value. This approach is not particularly promising because you have to calculate the day/date based on milliseconds. You will have to consider time zones / offsets, too. Do you know the package `java.time`?

Comment: Thank you for your response de Haar I appreciate your suggestion and yes I know about java.time package,Can you suggest me what I have to do next what type of approach will I take? and what code should I do?

Comment: Well, that depends on what exactly you are trying to do. Why do you pass a value in milliseconds? Where does it come from? You are obviously only interested in displaying a date or `"today"`/`"yesterday"`. Can you tell us the reasons? Btw, you can [edit] your question by clicking on the *edit* button.

Comment: I would not use `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`… If you know about `java.time`, you could look up how to use a `LocalDate` and an `Instant`, I think those are most suitable for your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
fun calculateTodayYesterday(time: Long) : String {
    val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

    if (currentTime - time > 2*86400000) {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
        return sdf.format(time)
    } else if (currentTime - time > 86400000) {
        return "Yesterday"
    } else {
        return "Today"
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine but still I have one issue when I enter System.CurrentMillis()*3 statically to print rest of days except Today and Yesterday it also prints today so what is the solution for this particular issue?

Check Below Link:-
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvSLfQcBDHBQjW3dGMPpNHJ-TCdp?e=pRshu3

Comment: `System.CurrentMillis()*3` is not a valid test use case because it is a day in the future, this case is not handled by `calculateTodayYesterday` function. So what kind of output should be in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

With `java.time` you can easily find out if a moment in time (`time: Long` as epoch millis) has a specific date (`LocalDate`) in a specific time zone (`ZoneId`).

Here's a possible modification of your code:

```kotlin
object DateTimeUtils {

    private val today by lazy {
        // date of today in system default time zone
        LocalDate.now()
    }

    // formatter for desired format of a LocalDate
    private val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                    "dd MMMM, uuuu",
                                            Locale.getDefault()
                                )

    fun calculateTodayYesterday(time: Long): String {
        // create a moment in time from the given millis
        val instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time)
        /*
         * use that moment to create a datetime in the time zone of the device/jvm,
         * and extract the date-part because that's the information needed
         */
        var givenDate = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
                                instant,
                                ZoneId.systemDefault()
                             ).toLocalDate()
        // directly return the result of the when-statement
        return when (givenDate) {
            today -> "Today"
            today.minusDays(1) -> "Yesterday"
            else -> givenDate.format(dateFormatter)
        }
    }
}
```

Example use in a `main`:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val todayMillis = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
    val yesterdayMillis = todayMillis - 86400000
    val millisBeforeYesterday = yesterdayMillis - 86405000

    println("Epoch millis $todayMillis: ${DateTimeUtils.calculateTodayYesterday(todayMillis)}")
    println("Epoch millis $yesterdayMillis: ${DateTimeUtils.calculateTodayYesterday(yesterdayMillis)}")
    println("Epoch millis $millisBeforeYesterday: ${DateTimeUtils.calculateTodayYesterday(millisBeforeYesterday)}")
}
```

Output of example use (default locale was `Locale.GERMANY`):

```
Epoch millis 1660120081052: today
Epoch millis 1660033681052: yesterday
Epoch millis 1659947276052: 08 August, 2022
```

Comment: Hello de-Haar Thank you for helping me i tried this above code but some how it not works in my IDE and shows some error and This EpochTime is version Dependent thus this code is no longer helpful to me Thank you

Comment: OK, may be helpful for future readers…